# iptables treating ssh and http requests differently

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssh, iptables, routing

Here are the facts:

- server (IP 192.168.1.140) that runs openssh on port 22 and nginx on port 80
- server sits behind firewall/router (IP 192.168.1.1) that has identical iptables rules for openssh and nginx
- from lan:

  - can access ssh
  - can access nginx
- from wan:

  - can access ssh
  - cannot access nginx (Operation times out: "Failed to connect to 0.0.0.80: No route to host")
  - There is no problem when using apache instead of nginx

My guess is that the http packets are getting dropped because my rules are limited to RELATED and ESTABLISHED connections, but my attempts at creating a NEW connection state rule have been unsuccessful. I'm also guessing that apache and nginx handle incoming connections differently, e.g., apache creates a new connection when it spawns a new worker but nginx does not.

Output of iptables -nvL on firewall:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   254 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
   78  6555 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2    80 syn_flood  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x02
  102 23292 input_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  102 23292 input      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
  569  202K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   12   804 forwarding_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   12   804 forward    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 reject     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
   55  6523 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  399  142K output_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  399  142K output     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain MINIUPNPD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   12   804 zone_lan_forward  all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 zone_wan_forward  all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain forwarding_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain forwarding_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   12   804 nat_reflection_fwd  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain forwarding_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   10   674 zone_lan   all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   92 22618 zone_wan   all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain input_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain input_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain input_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain nat_reflection_fwd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.140       tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.140       tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.140       tcp dpt:443

Chain output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  399  142K zone_lan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   17  1164 zone_wan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain output_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain reject (5 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2    80 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with tcp-reset
   90 22538 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain syn_flood (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2    80 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 25/sec burst 50
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   10   674 input_lan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   10   674 zone_lan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_lan_ACCEPT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  382  141K ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-lan  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   10   674 ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_lan_DROP (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-lan  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_lan_REJECT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 reject     all  --  *      br-lan  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 reject     all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_lan_forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   12   804 zone_wan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 forwarding_lan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 zone_lan_REJECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   92 22618 input_wan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   92 22618 zone_wan_REJECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_wan_ACCEPT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   28  1878 ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_wan_DROP (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_wan_REJECT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 reject     all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   92 22618 reject     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain zone_wan_forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MINIUPNPD  all  --  eth1   !eth1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140       tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140       tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140       tcp dpt:443
    0     0 forwarding_wan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 zone_wan_REJECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

**UPDATE:** tcpdump confirms that the firewall/router is filtering packets sent to port 80 so that they do not reaching the server.

Output of firewall/router tcpdump -i any -vv port 80:

```
0 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Output of server tcpdump -i any -vv port 80:

```
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I feel like my rules are only slightly off and would like to avoid enabling the TRACE target because its a hassle for openwrt (firewall/router).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ISP started blocking port 80. Rules themselves were fine as are both apache and nginx.

Answer (score 0):

This message

> Operation times out: "Failed to connect to 0.0.0.80: No route to host"

Is generated by NginX or some other software while trying to connect to this IP (0.0.0.80)
It is not related to port 80 filtering.

You can try to debug your filtering by:

> telnet 192.168.1.140 80
> from wan side
> and/or listening for packets from/to port 80 on both interfaces, inside and outside, to see if same packets appear on both sides.

Compare output of two :

> tcpdump -ni ${wan_interface} port 80 and host 192.168.1.140
>
> tcpdump -ni ${lan_interface} port 80 and host 192.168.1.140